# Search REST API Custom managed property return null

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, sharepoint-rest-api

My Custom managed property in Search REST API bring's null value in SharePoint Online.

```
/_api/search/query?sourceid='A09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81F-FEDFAB16C4E31'&selectproperties='Title,mycustomColumn'.
```

resultant XML:

```
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
<d:Key>mycustomColumn</d:Key>
<d:Value m:null="true"/>
<d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

However, I am getting default column 'Title' value and in the search schema, I checked "queryable"  and "searchable" option. But no luck getting my custom property.

Comment: in the site collection(s) this custom column exists, did you go into search and offline availability and initiate a reindex request?

Comment: Yes i am able to get value after initiating reindex...

Comment: so it is working now?